# MySql 'or' Operator not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the user from my database using email or username, my code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`Email`='".$User."' OR `Username`='".$User."'') AND `Password`='".$Password."'";
```

**My Code Worked**

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (Email = '$User' or Username ='$User') AND Password='$Password'";
```

Comment: Why isn't it working? What is your test data? Is it letting someone in who it shouldn't, or not letting anyone in?

Comment: Why, in 2013 (nearly 2014) aren't you using prepared statements?

Comment: Building SQL queries by sticking strings together is very dangerous. Use prepared statements instead! Also, variable names in PHP are traditionally spelled with lowercase initial letters.

Comment: When I added correct email it worked but when I type correct username it is not working.

Comment: Since the entire statement is wrapped in double quotes, you can simplify it: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`Email`='$User' OR `Username`='$User'') AND `Password`='$Password.'";. Now I can see an extra ' just before the ).

Comment: `='".$User."'') AND` looks like you've added too many `'`s...

Comment: @PhilPerry I have removed it but still not working

Comment: @user3133148 - can you echo out the query you're creating, and run it in the database directly? Assuming that you're running in `mysql_query`, is there anything in `mysql_error`?

Comment: Yeah, it just stopped working Monday. No one knows why.

Comment: The comment software ate the backticks as setting off code segments. I didn't intend for them to be removed. However, you did have `$User'')` instead of `$User')`. Did you fix that? What does the query have now? Are you getting any MySQL errors? Is $User defined (have a value)? And of course, your field names (Email, etc.) exactly match how the table is defined (same capitalization, etc.)?

Comment: "it just stopped working"... any changes to _your_ code that you know of? Any evidence of a hack of your site? Did your host upgrade PHP and/or MySQL versions?

Comment: Please redo your code to avoid [Sql Injection](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html)

Comment: A very good point @McAden `+1`

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I would have posted this in a comment (*believe me*), because the comment box doesn't show backticks properly (I know there's a trick to it, but I don't know it, *yet*.)

Use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE (`Email`='".$User."' OR `Username`='".$User."') 
AND `Password`='".$Password."'";
```

You had one too many quotes in `'".$User."''`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE (`Email`='".$User."' OR `Username`='".$User."'') 
                                                ----^
AND `Password`='".$Password."'";
```

- And do consider reading [**this article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) on how to prevent injection.

---

**Footnote:** And if by the slightest chance that you would be using the now-deprecated `mysql_*` functions, STOP and start using `mysqli_*` functions with prepared statements and/or PDO.

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`Email`='".$User."' OR `Username`='".$User."') AND `Password`='".$Password."'";
```

There was an extra quote after $user variable.